# ETS matching issue

Tags: erlang, pattern-matching

I am learning ETS. I did:

```
Sometab = ets:new(sometable, [bag]).
ets:insert(Sometab, {109, ash, 8}).
```

Then I typed:

```
ets:match(Sometab, {109, ash, '$1'}).
```

However instead of getting `8` - I am getting: `["\b"]` as output!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are getting the correct answer. However, the erlang shell prints `[8]` as `"\b"` since the ascii code for `backspace` is 8.

Erlang has no string type. Strings in erlang are represented simply as a list of integers and the Erlang shell prints this list as a string if the list contains integers withing the ascii range only.

This can indeed be confusing at times.

Comment: Oh! So when I pass this as output to say, a browser, it will be displayed fine then?

Comment: Well, yes... sort of. ["\b"] is the same thing as [[8]]. So if you want to get to the integer you can do something like [[X]] = ["\b"]. Now X will contain the integer 8.